# 2D walks on a square grid; The number of Paths leading to specific $(X,Y)$

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, multinomial-coefficients

### Introduction (1)

Lets have a 2D plane, and place a Walker in the center $(X,Y)=(0,0)$

Lets take a example where we use all of the possible moves, $(m = 9)$.

We have one such case, where the Walker can make one of the $9$ moves each turn: **Up, Down, Left, Right, Up-right, Down-right, Up-left, Down-left** or **Stay** where it is.

The following grids represent number of possible paths leading to each square after $n$ turns where the middle value is always the center:

> $$(n=1)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=2)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
>         2 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
>         3 & 6 & 9 & 6 & 3\\
>  2 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 2\\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=3)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1\\
>  3 & 9 & 18 & 21 & 18 & 9 & 3\\
>  6 & 18 & 36 & 42 & 36 & 18 & 6\\
>  7 & 21 & 42 & 49 & 42 & 21 & 7\\
>  6 & 18 & 36 & 42 & 36 & 18 & 6\\
>  3 & 9 & 18 & 21 & 18 & 9 & 3\\
>  1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$

And by observing the values we can conclude that in this case, the Number of possible paths ($P$) leading to a certain $(X,Y)$ coordinates is:

$$ P_{(x,y)}= \binom{n}{x}_2 \times \binom{n}{y}_2 $$

Where $\binom{a}{b}_2$ represents numbers in the [Trinomial triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle).

---

### Introduction (2)

Or lets say we allow only $4$ moves, $(m=4)$

We can observe a case with the set of moves: **Left, Right, Up** and **Down** :

> $$(n=1)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         - & 1 & - \\
>         1 & 0 & 1 \\
>         - & 1 & - \\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=2)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         - & - & 1 & - & -\\
>         - & 2 & 0 & 2 & -\\
>         1 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 1\\
>         - & 2 & 0 & 2 & -\\
>         - & - & 1 & - & -\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=3)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         - & - & - & 1 & - & - & -\\
>         - & - & 3 & 0 & 3 & - & -\\
>         - & 3 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 3 & -\\
>         1 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 1\\
>         - & 3 & 0 & 9 & 0 & 3 & -\\
>         - & - & 3 & 0 & 3 & - & -\\
>         - & - & - & 1 & - & - & -\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=4)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         - & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & - & -\\
>         - & - & - & 4 & 0 & 4 & - & - & -\\
>         - & - & 6 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 6 & - & -\\
>         - & 4 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 4 & -\\
>         1 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 36 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 1\\
>         - & 4 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 4 & -\\
>         - & - & 6 & 0 & 16 & 0 & 6 & - & -\\
>         - & - & - & 4 & 0 & 4 & - & - & -\\
>         - & - & - & - & 1 & - & - & - & -\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$

By rotating this 4-move case, where ($n=4$) for example, and removing the zero zones, 
we get a new grid:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1\\
        4 & 16 &24 & 16 & 4\\
        6 & 24 & 36 & 24 & 6\\
 4 & 16 & 24 & 16 & 4\\
 1 & 4 & 6 & 4 & 1\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Where the rotated $P'$ can be then easily calculated, assuming that the rotated center is at the bottom left corner $(X',Y')=(0,0)$ for the purposes of using the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) (the starting center is still in the center of the square):

$$P'_{(x,y)}= \binom{n}{x} \times \binom{n}{y}$$

The $4$ move case with moves **Up-right, Down-right, Up-left, Down-left** is the same thing but doesn't even need a rotation, we need to just remove the zero zones to get the same grid as above.

---

### Introduction (3)

But then, lets look at the example of $(m=8)$ where the only move missing is **Stay**, then it would look like this:

> $$(n=1)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         1 & 0 & 1 \\
>         1 & 1 & 1 \\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=2)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
>         2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2\\
>         3 & 4 & 8 & 4 & 3\\
>  2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2\\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$
>
> $$(n=3)$$
>   $$
>         \begin{matrix}
>         1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1\\
>  3 & 6 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 6 & 3\\
>  6 & 12 & 27 & 27 & 27 & 12 & 6\\
>  7 & 12 & 27 & 24 & 27 & 12 & 7\\
>  6 & 12 & 27 & 27 & 27 & 12 & 6\\
>  3 & 6 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 6 & 3\\
>  1 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1\\
>         \end{matrix}
> $$

How would now $P_{(x,y)}$ for $n$ moves be calculated?

---

### Question

> How could one solve and find $P(n,x,y)$ for a specific
>   configuration of allowed moves?

I'm mainly interested in the symmetrical ones. Although $9$ move and $4$ move ones were not that hard to figure out, the $5$ move ones ($4$ **sides** and **stay** moves / $4$ **corners** and **stay** moves) and $8$ move one (**corners** and **sides**) remain unsolved, even though they look very similar to the solved ones.

---

If this is also true in $1$ dimension where **right+left** moves produce the binomial triangle, and **right+left+stay** the trinomial triangle, supposedly then there should be a generalized method for higher dimensions too.

Comment: For the $4$-move case, turn the grid by $\pi/4$ to make the directions independent (see e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1692642)).

Comment: @joriki thanks, turns out it can be then easily calculated using a rotated version of the grid with binomial coefficients.

Comment: You may be interested in the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of a graph, which has the property that the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^\ell$ counts the number of walks from $i$ to $j$ in $\ell$ steps. Of course, you now have to compute the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^\ell$; doesn't seem much easier. But since $A$ is symmetric and real, it is diagonalizable: $A=S^{-1}DS$. Therefore, $A^\ell = S^{-1}D^\ell S$, and it is easy to take powers of a diagonal matrix. I don't know if this helps; I will sleep on it :)